# Firebase Crash Reporting without CocoaPods

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, run-script, firebase-crash-reporting

I'm implementing Firebase Crash Reporting in a project which doesn't use CocoaPods, and Firebase is working great, but when it comes to uploading the symbol files for readable crash logs, the `upload-sym` executable that is expected to be run at the end of the Xcode Run Script isn't present.

Upon further investigation, this file is available in the CocoaPods project, but it's not provided in the Firebase framework zip download.

Is it safe to copy the `upload-sym` files from another project's FirebaseCrash directory into this CocoaPod-less project so the symbol upload process can complete successfully?

I will report this to the Firebase team as well (although Frank will probably see this before I can complete the report, ha)

Comment: I don't see how it would be *unsafe*, so I would just give it a try.  You'll need more than just upload-sym, as there is an include file in the same folder that goes with it.  If you're not able to get it to work, I can get one of the iOS folks to chime in (I'm more on the Android side).

Comment: Hi Doug, if I include the 5 files it appears to work as expected. That's the three upload-sym files, batch-upload and dump_syms. Thanks for your help!

Comment: surprised that this seems to still not be included. downloaded via newest podspec: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=firebasecrash

Comment: There's a fulsome answer to this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513092/upload-symbol-files?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The latest zip file now has the upload-sym tool under Firebase/Crash (the download link can be found at https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks)