# Firebase crash reporting doesn't recognise (symbolicate) function name

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

Everything is working fine, in my `viewDidload(:)` I am calling `fatalError()` and the app is crashing, But when it comes to the crash reporting console it doesn't show the function name as you can see below. Am I missing something regarding the integration or is this a default behavior ?

[image]

Comment: How did you install Firebase?

Comment: @shallowThought using cocoapods `pod 'Firebase/Core'`
and `pod 'Firebase/Crash'`

Comment: Might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513092/upload-symbol-files